# import modin.pandas and ray() don't close file

Tags: python, ray, modin

I'm trying to use modin and ray() but I can't move file after read it. In line  shutil.move(f"./IMPORT/"+file,f"./IMPORTED/"+file)

file is still open, there is some way to close it and move it in other folder?

Here is entire code:

```
    import os
    from pathlib import Path
    import shutil
    import ray
    import ray.util
    ray.init()
    import modin.pandas as pd
    
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    import_folder_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'IMPORT')
    folder_path: Path = Path(import_folder_path)
    file_list = []
    
    file_list = list(
        filter(lambda x: x if x.endswith('.xlsx') else None,
        os.listdir(folder_path))
    )
    df2 = []
    if len(file_list):
        excl_list=[]
        excl_merged = pd.DataFrame()
        imported_file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'IMPORTED\\')
        for file in file_list:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file)
            df=pd.read_excel(file_path)
            df = df[df['Delivery Status'] != 'Delivered']
            df2 = df.append(df)
            shutil.move(f"./IMPORT/"+file,f"./IMPORTED/"+file)
    
        output_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,'output.xlsx')
        df2.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False)
    else:
        print("No excel file found")
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Side note, you have `df2 = df.append(df)` where you meant `df2 = df2.append(df)`.  Please show us the traceback you get.

Comment: What do you mean by "file is still open"

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts here is traceback:  'Si è verificata un'eccezione: PermissionError
[WinError 32] Impossibile accedere al file. Il file è utilizzato da un altro processo: './IMPORT/abc (1).xlsx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\angelo\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    shutil.move(f"./IMPORT/"+file,f"./IMPORTED/"+file)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mention of this problem in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29803.  The suggested workaround is to manage the file handle lifetime yourself:

```
...
        for file in file_list:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file)
            with open(file_path,"rb") as xlfile:
                df=pd.read_excel(xlfile)
```

Pandas can read from a file handle, and this way the `with` ensures the handle is closed.

Comment: Hi Tim, I change the code as you suggested but I found a new issue error is here:  'Si è verificata un'eccezione: TypeError
Could not serialize the argument <_io.BufferedReader name='C:\\IMPORT\\abc (1).xlsx'> for a task or actor modin.core.execution.ray.common.engine_wrapper._deploy_ray_func. Check https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-core/objects/serialization.html#troubleshooting for more information.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    df=pd.read_excel(xlfile)

Comment: Does it work if you import `pandas` instead of `modin.pandas`?

Comment: Hi Tim, yes it works without any issue. Using modin, file is still open

Comment: Then that's a bug in `modin`.  Perhaps you should file a bug report with that project.

Comment: Hi Tim, yes I forwarded issue to develper. I'll back to you soon, thank you for now.